# How do I display all attributes from a rails select statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Please would it be possible to know how to display the :user_id, :player_id and :amount attributes together in a hash from the below code?

At the moment the array created returns player_id as the key and amount as the value {1695=>100, 1714=>200} whereas I need something like {1695=>{:user_id,100}?

The code in the controller is as follows:

```
@duplicates = Bid.select(:player_id, :user_id, :amount).group(:player_id).having("count(*) > 1").maximum(:amount)
```

The code in the view:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:white;">
      <%= @duplicates %><br>
  </div>
```

Comment: here `11695=>100` which one is amount and what is user_id? And `{1695=>{:user_id,100}` is not valid Ruby syntax. :) Tell it correctly.

Comment: amount is 100 and player id is 1695 :) and I want the key of the player id in this case 1695 to return a value of {:user_id, :amount} so there are 2 values associated with the :player_id key :) is this possible to achieve with a hash construct in ruby via the select statement or is there a better way?

Comment: Ok, then your correct syntax will be `{1695=>[:user_id,100]` .. code like `@duplicates.map! { |rec| {rec. player_id => [rec.user_id, rec.amount]}`

Comment: The select statement doesn't seem to be allowing me to access rec.player_id and the other attributes in the same way as you would usually access them through a Bid Object so the @duplicates.map! { |rec| {rec. player_id => [rec.user_id, rec.amount]}} is not working. Is there a better way to do this instead of using the @duplicates = Bid.select(:player_id, :user_id, :amount).group(:player_id).having("count(*) > 1").maximum(:amount) statement?

Comment: you did the query to the DB get result data. Now with `.map` you are decorating the data to present or use it some where else. So can you say what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Any error or no value?

Comment: The data does not get displayed via .map as I get the error "undefined method `player_id' for [1695, 100]:Array"

Comment: Ok, change the query to `@duplicates = Bid.select("player_id, user_id, MAX(amount)").group(:player_id).having("count(*) > 1")`

Comment: Great thanks the new query worked!! :)

Comment: Nice to know and the what about `.map` ? :)

Comment: Yes that works too! :)

Comment: awesome! ... enjoy.

Comment: I added it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to add the answer which we came up from the conversations in comments of the main post:

```
@duplicates = Bid.
  select("player_id, user_id,MAX(amount)").
  group(:player_id).
  having("count(*) > 1")
```

Now decorate the result as per your usecase:

```
@duplicates.map! do |rec| 
  { rec. player_id => [ rec.user_id, rec.amount ] }
end
```